# Change the log level of package/class in GCP Dataflow

Tags: java, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I want to change the log level of a specific package/class (`com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport`) in my Dataflow written on Apache Beam Java. Because when I'm setting the log level to the Dataflow as INFO, I see a lot of noise coming from this HttpTransport class, but I want to see only my INFO logs.

I'm able to override it with code configuration:

I used my custom pipeline option that extends DataflowWorkerLoggingOptions

```
var workerLogLevelOverrides = new DataflowWorkerLoggingOptions.WorkerLogLevelOverrides();
            workerLogLevelOverrides.addOverrideForClass(HttpTransport.class, DataflowWorkerLoggingOptions.Level.ERROR);
            options.setWorkerLogLevelOverrides(workerLogLevelOverrides);
```

But when I'm trying to do the same using start parameter **--workerLogLevelOverrides={"com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport":"ERROR"}** I'm getting following error:

```
Unable to parse JSON value {com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport:ERROR}

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to parse JSON value {com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport:ERROR}
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1953)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.access$400(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:146)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory$Builder.as(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:329)
    at com.macys.commonservices.ivs.ingestion.enrich.supplydemand.pipeline.EnrichSupplyDemandPipeline.main(EnrichSupplyDemandPipeline.java:26)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.codehaus.mojo.exec.ExecJavaMojo$1.run(ExecJavaMojo.java:282)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
Caused by: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot construct instance of `java.util.LinkedHashMap` (although at least one Creator exists): no String-argument constructor/factory method to deserialize from String value ('{com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport:ERROR}')
 at [Source: UNKNOWN; line: -1, column: -1]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:63)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1429)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleMissingInstantiator(DeserializationContext.java:1059)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator._createFromStringFallbacks(ValueInstantiator.java:371)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.ValueInstantiator.createFromString(ValueInstantiator.java:258)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:357)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:345)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.std.MapDeserializer.deserialize(MapDeserializer.java:29)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.deserializeNode(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1807)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.tryParseObject(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1839)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.options.PipelineOptionsFactory.parseObjects(PipelineOptionsFactory.java:1951)
    ... 9 common frames omitted
```

I tried both options: with deprecated `workerLogLevelOverrides` and the new `sdkHarnessLogLevelOverrides`.

Edit 1:
Here is the list of commands that I tried:

1. `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.WordCount -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner --project=my-project --stagingLocation=gs://my-bucket/staging --templateLocation=gs://my-bucket/templates/wordcount  --tempLocation=gs://my-bucket/templates/temp/ --workerLogLevelOverrides={\"com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport\":\"ERROR\"}"`
2. `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.WordCount -Dexec.args="--runner=DataflowRunner --project=my-project --stagingLocation=gs://my-bucket/staging --templateLocation=gs://my-bucket/templates/wordcount  --tempLocation=gs://my-bucket/templates/temp/ --workerLogLevelOverrides={'com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport':'ERROR'}"`
3. `mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=org.example.WordCount -Dexec.args='--runner=DataflowRunner --project=my-project --stagingLocation=gs://my-bucket/staging --templateLocation=gs://my-bucket/templates/wordcount  --tempLocation=gs://my-bucket/templates/temp/ --workerLogLevelOverrides={"com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport":"ERROR"}'`

They all failing with the above exception

Answer (score 0):

The parameter `--workerLogLevelOverrides={"com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport":"ERROR"}` seems correct.

It seems that your parameter is not taken as literal -- and quotes (`"`) are not passed as part of the parameter.

Are you using Shell scripts? If so, have you tried escaping any quotes, or wrapping them in single quotes (`'`)?

Comment: Yes, I'm running the command in Shell. 
Yes, I tried with a backslash (\) and a single quotes (').

Do I have to extend DataflowWorkerLoggingOptions to be able to override the worker log level, if I'm doing it via --workerLogLevelOverrides ?

Comment: You shouldn't need. It seems to be related to how you're passing the parameter and not the parameter itself. This should help https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30903/how-to-escape-quotes-in-shell

Comment: Bruno, thanks for your advice. I tested with different various and they all didn't work. I edited the original post and added all the commands that I used. Can you please check, if they are correct?

Comment: Can you try `--workerLogLevelOverrides='"'"'{"com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport":"ERROR"}'"'"'`? It seems weird but it would force a single quotes around `workerLogLevelOverrides`. I feel this becomes somewhat more complicated since you are using exec:java and wrapping parameters inside `exec.args`

Comment: wow! it's working!! Thank you very much! Is there any way to simplify this?

Comment: Maybe by using your IDE to call the class or java -jar. I think parameter passing through exec:java makes it extra annoying.